# Windows Phone 8 In App Purchasing

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

I want in app purchasing in my Windows Phone 8 app. I published my app as beta and also 3 products for this app that u can buy. I copied my ID from Dev Center in Visual Studio 2013. Now I want to test it.
The Problem is when I click on this button:

```
    private async void buttonInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        var listing = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();
        foreach (var product in listing.ProductListings)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2},{3}, {4}",
                product.Key,
                product.Value.Name,
                product.Value.FormattedPrice,
                product.Value.ProductType,
                product.Value.Description));
        }

        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "List all products", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

Then the messageBox  appears but has no Content. Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed after a day. no changes in code. xD maybe Servers were not ready

Answer (score 0):

You can just debug on it.. make sure

await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync()

returns the result you expected

Comment: Telling someone to just "debug it" isn't really helpful, is it?